# PowerDesigner 16.5 - columns names in SQL Server CREATE Database script

Tags: sql-server, powerdesigner

I have physical data model of my database in PowerDesigner 16.5 and I'd like to generate SQL Server 2012 CREATE Database script. 
The problem is that when I generate such file, columns names of tables are the same as defined on model's in "CODE" column, and I want them to be the same as in "NAME" column of table.

Do you know how to force PowerDesigner to get columns names from "Name" instead of "Code" during the process of generating file mentioned before?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the SQL generation pattern in the DBMS properties. In Database menu, there should be an "Edit current DBMS..." menu item, which opens the dialog with all the generation patterns.

There, you can find all those generations that include columns (column itself, table, reference, index, etc.) and replace "COLUMN" (or "COLNCODE") with "COLNNAME".

Be aware, however, that it might take quite a few iterations to discover all such places. Also, I would highly recommend to back up the database properties file - *.xdb - first, because it's rather easy to break something, and the entire DB generation will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the naming conventions under `Tools > Model Options > Naming Convention > Table > Code`, setting `Character case` as `Mixed CASe`, and `Valid characters` as `All valid`. That way all the future objects will have a `Code` matching their `Name`.

However... I find it easier to have slightly constrained SQL names, to avoid having to quote them everywhere they are used; plus it forces me to think twice about the `code` / SQL name, which make them more stable: I avoid jumping between "Employee in charge", "Responsible employee", "Dead-man pusher", which would update the SQL name; I settle for "RespEmpl" (let say all SQL names must have 4 or 8 characters), and keep fiddling with the `Name`until I'm fed up.

OK... I cannot find a way to apply again the Name-to-Code conversion on existing objects, after changing the `Model Options`, so here is a script which does that:

```
option explicit
   ' avoid endless loop in case of some mistake, adjust to model objects number
   ' set to -1 to disable
   const maxcount = 1000
   dim count : count = 0
   dim f : set f = ActiveModel
   descent f
sub descent(f)
   if maxcount > 0 and count > maxcount then exit sub
   output "... entering " & f.Name
   dim c
   for each c in f.Children
      count = count + 1
      if maxcount > 0 and count > maxcount then exit for
      if c.ClassKind = cls_Table then
         rename c
      elseif isKindOf(c.ClassKind, cls_BaseFolder) then
         descent c
      end if
   next
end sub
sub rename(o)
   dim n : n = o.Code
   o.setNameToCode
   if o.Code <> n then output "   " & o.ClassName & " " & o.Name & ", " & n & " => " & o.Code
end sub
```